# Why wont my uitableview save the changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am learning a bit of xcode and digging around on some premade code from a friend and one of my tableviews is not saving the changes after pressing done. I have attached a gif showing what happens. I deselect two sports from the list, then press done, go back to the page and it has rechecked both of the sports. I have pasted the code below.

https://imgflip.com/gif/kftqf

```
- (IBAction)btnSelectSportsClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btnSelectSportClicked = (UIButton *)sender;
    btnSelectSportClicked.enabled = NO;
    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            btnSelectSportClicked.enabled = YES;
    });
    self.sporttype = @"sport";
    self.tempSports = self.Sportsstring;
    self.Sports = [[[GlobalData sharedInstance] loadSports] mutableCopy];

    NSMutableDictionary *Data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [Data setObject:self.sporttype forKey:@"SportType"];
    [Data setObject:self.tempSports forKey:@"tempsport"];
    [Data setObject:self.Sports forKey:@"sport"];
    [Data setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"isAllowSelection"];
    self.sportSelectionview =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SportSelectionView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.sportSelectionview setDelegate:self];
    [self.sportSelectionview initdata:Data];
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    [self.view addSubview:self.sportSelectionview];
    [self.sportSelectionview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenSize.height, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                     animations:^{
                         [self.sportSelectionview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];
                     }];

}

-(void)btnDoneClicked:(id)sender selectedData:(NSMutableDictionary *)selected
{

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    [self.sportSelectionview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                 animations:^{
                     [self.sportSelectionview setFrame:CGRectMake(0,  screenSize.height, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];

                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     [self.sportSelectionview removeFromSuperview];
                 }];

    if([self.sporttype isEqualToString:@"sport"]){
        self.Sportsstring = [selected objectForKey:@"sports"];
    }else{
        self.BusinessSportsstring = [selected objectForKey:@"sports"];
    }
    NSLog(@"Sportstring :%@  BusinessSport : %@",self.Sportsstring ,self.BusinessSportsstring);
}
```

Comment: Which part of the code are you expecting to do the "saving"? I can't see any in the code you have listed

Comment: I have added the code for the 'Done' button, is there anything there that specifics the saving for the sportSelectionview ?

Comment: You never save anything here though.

Comment: Any idea on how I can save?

Comment: It *seems* like you are getting some values from the dictionary and setting them to properties. You are also logging those values. You need to either use [plists](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?tag=ios-saving-data-to-plist-tutorial) or [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html).